# I want to create React Native App, but getting this error. What can I do?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mkdir, mkdirection

Actual image here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1avqikjxB6n2dnBNh9qZ0Yugk7kNki8wb

Terminal output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720] (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Khalid Babu\Desktop\ReactNative>npx react-native init firstApp
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Khalid'
command not found: react-native
...
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a React app or a React Native app?

Comment: I doubt too many people are going to go and open some random google doc - you should include the error message in your question.

Comment: What is the error? I don't see it. Please include error as plain text here in your question.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app

Comment: I edited my question. Please, check it. I did some mistakes.

Comment: It is **probably** because of the space in your user directory. You are making an app in a directory called "Khalid Babu"while the terminal looks for "Khalid' directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed `react-native-cli` globally

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

than

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Also, there are some Prerequisites. Please check it as well.

1. Download and install JDK (v7 or newer)
2. Download and install Node
3. Download and install Android Studio Create an environment variable
   with the Java SDK path:

Windows → Search → System → Advanced System Settings → Environment variables → New

JAVA_HOME: C:\path\to\JavaSDK

For more detail visit mentioned in the below link

https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65